# JDBC metadata doesn't recognize mysql data types

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

I'm trying to create a method to recognize MySQL datatypes to create queries, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Here is the code that fails:

```
int type = meta.returnDataType(data[i], table);

if(type == 4){
    preparedStatement.setString(i + 1, data[i]);
    System.out.println("String går");
}if(type == 12){
    preparedStatement.setInt(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(data[i]));
    System.out.println("int går");
}else if(type == 92){
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    preparedStatement.setTime(i + 1, new java.sql.Time(formatter.parse(data[i]).getTime()));
}else if(type == 93){
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm");
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(i + 1, new java.sql.Timestamp(formatter.parse(data[i]).getTime()));
}
```

and here's my `returnDataType` method:

```
try(Connection con = DBConnection.getMySQLDataSourceForUpdate().getConnection();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement()){
    String query = "select * from " + table;

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    return rsmd.getColumnType(1);

}catch(IOException e){

}catch (SQLException e){

}
```

Now the problem is that it doesn't recognize varchar, even though the number 12 is returned every time I try it with system out print. When I try to detect it with if statements or switch, the result is either that they only register integers or they treat everything as integers. I can't seem to see why this is the case.

My CSV file goes like this, the first is an int and the second is a String. At least that's what it should be and that's the way it is in the database.

```
1,Per Lauvås
2,Per Per
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `returnDataType` method always returns the type of the **first column** of a table. You need to fix that. You should use the parameter metadata of the prepared statement, or maybe the column metadata from `DatabaseMetaData`. Or at least access the right column index.

You also have switched your if-branches. Type `4` is `java.sql.Types.INTEGER`, but you attempt to set it as a string, while type `12` is `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR`, but you try to set it as an integer (with a conversion that might fail).

Sidenote: You should not use integer values like 4, 12, 92 and 93, instead you should use the `java.sql.Types` constants `INTEGER`, `VARCHAR`, `TIME` and `TIMESTAMP`. It will make your code more readable and make it easier to detect mistakes like the above.